# Set Dataframe values to values in another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to merge two dataframes about movies on their title columns. Unfortunately they don't share indices, are ordered differently, and do not contain all the same movies. I have cleaned up the titles enough to the point where I can compare them and determine whether they are acceptably similar to be called the same movie. Following that comparison I am trying to set those "matching" titles equal to eachother (taking the title from df2 and overwriting it's equivalent in df), but I can't seem to get it to work.

This is df.head(10)

```
      Unnamed: 0                                       title    imdb_id  \
72            72                                   Gully Boy  tt2395469   
767          767                                   Long Shot  tt2139881   
1000        1000                                      Little  tt8085790   
1285        1285                                       Dumbo  tt3861390   
1342        1342                           Don"t Stop Me Now  tt9260446   
1358        1358  How to Train Your Dragon: The Hidden World  tt2386490   
1621        1621                               Captive State  tt5968394   
1658        1658                   Spider-Man: Far from Home  tt6320628   
1944        1944                           Avengers: Endgame  tt4154796   
1946        1946                              Captain Marvel  tt4154664
```

This is df2.head(10)

```
      Unnamed: 0  bo_year_rank                                      title  \
7455           0             1                           Avengers Endgame   
7456           1             2                              The Lion King   
7457           2             3                            Captain Marvel    
7458           3             4                   Spider-Man Far from Home   
7459           4             5                                Toy Story 4   
7460           5             6                                    Aladdin   
7461           6             7         Fast  Furious Presents Hobbs  Shaw   
7462           7             8                        The Wandering Earth   
7463           8             9                                     Ne Zha   
7464           9            10  How to Train Your Dragon The Hidden World
```

The comparison function I am using:

```
def fix_stupid_titles(title, list_titles, min_score=0):
    # -1 score incase we don't get any matches
    max_score = -1
    # Returning empty name for no match as well
    max_title = ""
    # Iterating over all names in the other
    for title2 in list_titles:
        #Finding fuzzy match score
        score = fuzz.ratio(title, title2)
        # Checking if we are above our threshold and have a better score
        if (score > min_score) & (score > max_score):
            max_title = title2
            max_score = score

    return (title, max_title, max_score)
```

My thought is to iterate through one dataframe and apply the stupid_titles function to check similarity, but then I'm not sure how to update the titles so they are equal.

```
for i, title in enumerate(df.title):
    thing=fix_stupid_titles(title, df2.title, min_score=75)
    #thing saves the return of the functoin (title, max_title, score)
    df['title'][thing[1]]=thing[0]
```

I want the titles in `df` to be overwritten with the titles from `df2` when the function determines they are similar.

Any help would be appreciated! Or suggestions on how to go about this more efficiently.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve it with the [`process`](https://kite.com/python/docs/fuzzywuzzy.process") of fuzzywuzzy.

```
df_choices = df['title'].values
```

This will get the list of title from your `df` Dataframe

```
def fuzzratio(row, options):
    match, score = process.extractOne(row['title'], options, scorer=fuzz.ratio)
    row['matches'] = match
    row['score'] = score
    return row

matches = df2.apply(lambda x: fuzzratio(x, df_choices), axis=1)
matches.columns = ['title', 'matches', 'score']
```

The function `fuzzratio` is used to get best match title for all titles in your `df2` Dataframe.

```
merges = df2.merge(matches, on='title', how = 'inner')
merges = merges.loc[merges['score'] >= 90]
merges.drop('score', axis=1, inplace=True)
merges.columns = ['new_title', 'title']
```

Filter all the title which have score greater than 75.

```
df = df.merge(merges, on='title', how = 'left')
df.loc[~df['new_title'].isna(), 'title'] = df['new_title']
df.drop('new_title', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Merge the original `df` with titles from `merges` dataframe. After merge, overwrite the titles.

I hope this helps.